# How do I remove the black statusbar on Vimperator for Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, vimperator

I recently installed Vimperator and found it awesome, however not really fitting for my everyday tasks. So instead of disabling and enabling it each time, I decided to keep it enabled and show the Firefox toolbar.

My only problem is that the black (or other colors depending on the security of the site) bar at the bottom breaks the persona induced eye-candy. Is there any way to permanently change the color of the bar, or hide it while I'm using Vimperator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vimperator has a "highlight" function that allows you to alter the CSS behind the display. As Firefox's entire chrome is styled with this same CSS, there's not much you can't do.

```
:highlight -append StatusLine {CSS}
```

You can change text and background colours with color:colour; background-color:colour;, and possibly set background:none; to let the persona shine through - but not using them and not having that deep an understanding of how FF's Chrome works, I couldn't tell you for sure.

Comment: Wow, this is great. One question through, its a good idea using background:none for interacting with my Firefox Persona, but is there a way to remove Vimperator's text?

Comment: I found it, I can actually use opacity:0. The problem is that it also makes my statusbar icons visible. Any way to be able to see them?

Comment: @Martín Fixman: I suppose you could use an all-blank font, but you'd really have to ask someone who knows more about FF or Vimp.

Answer (score 2):

Just use

```
:set ls=0
```

If you want to make this change permanent, add it to your `vimperatorc` file.

Use `:help laststatus` for more info.